# OData webservice quering from VS Service Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, odata, tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I want to send request like this:

```
/odata.svc/Pages(ItemId=27,PublicationId=1)
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
CdService.ContentDeliveryService cdService = new ContentDeliveryService(new Uri("http://xxx.xx:81/odata.svc"));
var pages = cdService.Pages;
pages = pages.AddQueryOption("ItemId", "270");
pages = pages.AddQueryOption("PublicationId", "2");
var result = pages.Execute();
```

My problem is that this code is sending request like this:

```
/odata.svc/Pages()?ItemId=270&PublicationId=2
```

The problem with this request is that it returns me all the pages there are and not just the one I need.

I could use LINQ:

```
result.Single(page => page.ItemId == 27 && page.PublicationId == 1);
```

But the problem is that all the pages will still be sent over the wire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a quick test with LINQ and it seems to be doing the correct query:

```cs
ContentDeliveryService.ContentDeliveryService service = 
    new ContentDeliveryService.ContentDeliveryService(new Uri("http://localhost:99/odata.svc"));
var page = from x in service.Pages
            where x.ItemId == 2122
                    && x.PublicationId == 16
            select x;
foreach (var page1 in page)
{
    Console.WriteLine(page1.Title);
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thansk, I prefer this syntax: `cdService1.Pages.Where(p => p.ItemId == 27 && p.PublicationId == 1).First();`

Comment: :) As I said, it was a "quick test"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor = service.Entities.Where(c => 
               c.Entity is CDService.Page 
               && ((CDService.Page)c.Entity).ItemId == pageId.ItemId 
               && ((CDService.Page)c.Entity).PublicationId == pageId.PublicationId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

if (entityDescriptor != null)
{
   return (CDService.Page)entityDescriptor.Entity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, although not very nice:

```
ContentDeliveryService cdService1 
                = new ContentDeliveryService(new Uri("http://xxx.xx:81/odata.svc"));
var page = cdService1.Execute<Page>(
             new Uri("http://xxx.xx:81/odata.svc/Pages(ItemId=27,PublicationId=1)"));
```